# iPhone app crashing in 4.0 when switching between apps in background

Tags: iphone, background, iphone-4

I have an iphone application which has to support multitasking. But when i open the app and do some work then close, it is going to background and when open different app and then again switch to my own app it is crashing..

Don't have idea about when i did mistake..

it is giving error like this:

[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to remove an object in an immutable array, it doesn't seem to be a multitasking problem..